# mysql update row to previous enum value

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

I have a simple MYSQL table with 2 columns:

```
id | status
 1 |  b
```

`status` is `ENUM('a','b','c')`

I want to update this row so that if:

1) The current status is `c` then new value `b`

2) The current status is `b` then new value `a`

3) The current status is `a` then do nothing

I tried the following but of course is not working:

```
UPDATE table SET status = status - 1 WHERE id = '1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET status = case status when 'b' then 'a'
                                          when 'c' then 'b' end
WHERE id = '1' and status <> 'a'
```

(`<> 'a'` in `WHERE` is to avoid 'a'-rows in transaction.)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
update table_name
set status = case when status = 'c' then 'b'
                  when status = 'b' then 'a'
                  when status = 'a' then 'a'
             end
 where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an index value for enum types, so your approach to doing `status = status - 1` was a good approach.

As the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html) says:

> Each enumeration value has an index:
>
> - The elements listed in the column specification are assigned index numbers, beginning with 1.
> - The index value of the empty string error value is 0. This means that you can use the following SELECT statement to find rows into which invalid ENUM values were assigned: `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE enum_col=0;`
> - The index of the NULL value is NULL.
> - The term “index” here refers to a position within the list of enumeration values. It has nothing to do with table indexes.

So in your case these are the index values:

- NULL: NULL
- '' (empty): 0
- 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3

Based on this, you can simply write:

```
update table set status=status-1 where status>1 and id=1;
```